# AndEngine View in ViewFlipper

Tags: android, andengine

I'm trying to make a game and I plan to use both andengine and normal android views (that makes the menus a lot easier) in my game and as i have to maintain a connection to a server I would like to do that in one activity (so i don't have to establish the connection again once i change to the andengine). Now my question is: Can i put the andengine View inside of a viewflipper? (Currently i am inflating my different views in the flipper and then add them to it, can i do it the same way with the andengine view and where do i have to put the GameActivity stuff then?)

Thank you guys for helping me out ;D

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes. You can embed an "AndEngine View" into a layout. It get's problematic though when the layout is scrollable, since the view stays 'in place' where it originally was, with the layout kind of scrolling below it. Anyway I had tried this a long time ago and I've never tried it in a ViewFlipper. I'd just give it a try and let us know how it went.

To get you started, check out this example: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2-AnchorCenter/src/org/andengine/examples/XMLLayoutExample.java

Comment: Hi Nicolas - this appears to still start a new activity (and exit the current one), and I believe the original question was whether you can utilize the AndEngine while staying in a "plain-vanilla" activity. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

While you can use andengine as part of a standard layout, you will encounter problems using it within ViewFlippers and Tabhosts among others. An andengine game activity extends SurfaceView and SurfaceViews behave a bit differently from the rest of android's views. You may have better luck with a ViewPager instead. In my expereince it works in some views, and not in others.
here are some older posts about SurfaceViews and View flippers not loving each other:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/ZuOKNsE3jPs

But I would like to add bit of opinion based on my own expereince, and also the findings of the authors of [AndEngine for Android Game Development Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/184951898X) in that the time savings coding menus in standard android views is paid for in poor user experience. 
The reason for this is that initializing the engine and loading and releasing textures is a pretty greedy process, and will cause the screen to sit black and unresponsive  It makes the user wait. But if you implement you menus in the engine you get two big benefits: faster responsiveness and the ability to make cool animated transitions from one screen to the next.

So for my 2 cents worth, consider using andengine to make your menus. I'm currently rebuilding a game I made using mixed and andenging views to use only andengine views. I think its the best way.